# Spring data Jpa vs Spring Jdbc for lookup tables

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In our project we are using spring data jpa (which I really like)but when it comes to small lookup tables im thinking would it be advantageous to use spring jdbc (write the query ourselves) instead of jpa. Consider 25 independent lookup tables(no relation between them) with just 10 rows, 2 columns of data. Here we will have to create 25 repositories ,25 entities , so 50 beans in memory just to perform one operation (fetch all lookup data).With jdbc, we can write 25 methods to query these tables. So purely from performance point , in this case, does jdbc performs better than spring data jpa? But as mentioned before I’m more inclined towards spring data jpa as it’s less code. Is there any way to reduce these number of beans in spring data jpa. Please note, we are not allowed to make any changes to dB, adding new tables/views/columns etc. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all JDBC is faster then the JPA which reduces the load into Application side. Secondly, if you need column from multiple tables without adding any changes in DB, then my suggestion is to go with JDBC Query.